# webstorm - meteor doesn't restart - how to remove --once option?

Tags: meteor, webstorm

I'm using webstorm for meteor dev. 
I've configured a meteor project, and can run my app
however, making a change doesn't trigger the meteor server to restart or rebuild, as it does when running a normal server instance.

Looking at the command being run, they have inserted `--once` into the command line:

```
/usr/local/bin/meteor --once run --settings private/local.json
```

I've added the --settings option in the config dialog.
is there a way to remove that? I guess it will mean a lot of restarts with how webstorm works but so be it. the alternative - manually restarting the whole server all the time is not usable.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/meteor-support-in-webstorm-9/

> When WebStorm runs Meteor it uses the -once which disables Meteor’s
>   auto reload feature. The reason for this is that the way it currently
>   works is incompatible with WebStorms autosave option. We are working
>   with the Meteor team/community to try and think of ways in which we
>   could provide this feature from within WebStorm. But that it still in
>   the works.

Comment: WebStorm has just fixed the issue after I file it. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm's autosave feature is *evil*, and [hundreds of people](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6460) have [complained](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/439007) about it.

WebStorm should run meteor without the `--once` parameter, which will enable you to save when you deem it's a good time to do so. To that effect, disable Appearance & Behavior -> System settings -> Save files on frame deactivation and Save files automatically if..., and assign a keyboard shortcut to File -> Save or File -> Save All.

**UPDATE**

Funny how this has -1 votes, when JetBrains has recognized the problem and [fixed the issue in WebStorm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14045#comment=27-846895).

Comment: I see how to add the "save" key-command, but i'm not sure I can disable the --once, so i guess i'll just forget running meteor inside webstorm.

Comment: @dcsan: Damn you JetBrains, for being so stubborn about that stupid Autosave feature. I've filed an [issue against it; please vote](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14045).

Comment: what's the problem with autosave, if you can disable it that easily? I quite like the way webstorm will save *all* documents. the way meteor is with slow-restarting when you save a single doc makes it a pain in sublime when you have multiple files.

Comment: The problem is Jetbrains is so stubborn about Autosave, they think they need to "work with the Meteor team to come up with a solution". No, there's no need for that. Let the user save when they want, just don't *think* in terms of autosave-is-king, which is what let to passing `--once`.

Comment: I discovered other problems with their watchers running all the time and creating temp files too, which I was unable to disable. So, back to sublime. I like it much more anyway, feels like coming back from editing with blurry goggles underwater.

Comment: > discovered other problems with their watchers running all the time and creating temp files too —— you can disable creating 'temp' files in the configurable with other 'save' settings

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to remove it but I was able to create a **Bash** script to run my server command instead of doing it in the console. I'm using **PhpStorm** I believe it should be the same.

1. The first thing you need to do is create a simple `bash` script which is essentially is the code you'd run in console.  Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
meteor --settings settings.json
```

1. Once the file is created, go to `Run->Edit Configurations`.
2. Under `Defaults` select `Bash` and click the plus sign at the top left of the modal.
3. Name your script. `Name:`
4. Reference your script. `Script:`

[image]

5. Select `Run '[Script Name]'` from the `Run` menu.

[image]

*Hopefully this is helpful and helps a few people.*